# Firebase storage Image cache not working

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

There are two image uri, first one is located in **firebase storage** and second one is a sample image in **react-native blog**.

And I believe recat-native's `Image` component is cacheable.

```
<View>
   <Image 
       style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
       source={{ uri : 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/siren-5eee7.appspot.com/o/profile%2FmO2vxzWDbJRzM5ckzCBXtf0aPhV2?alt=media'}}
    />

    <Image 
       style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
       source={{ uri : 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/react-native-congratulations.png'}}
    />
<View>
```

**Problem**

I think firebase storage's image is not cached. when I render screen it always trying to download. So the second image load faster, and after one second, firebase image is loaded.

**How can I make firebase storage image cacheable?**

You can test above code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.SettableMetadata#cacheControl

See this documentation I think you have to set metadata while storing the image to the Firebase storage.

Comment: So during image upload, I should set that, right ??

Comment: Done! `storageRef.put(blob, { cacheControl: 'max-age=31536000', contentType : `${image.mime}` })`

Comment: Can you set this after the fact/ once the images are already uploaded?