# Angular cache images when already loaded?

Tags: angular, image, caching, offline

we display item image in item list page when click on each item go to item detail.

the problem we don't want to load image again just take it from item list to display

how to solve this?.

Comment: pass item as @Input from list when you click open. the browser does cache your image. post some code you will get better help

Comment: check this out : https://itnext.io/improve-your-angular-app-performance-by-using-this-simple-observable-cache-decorator-71e81dfa76ae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most browsers by default cache the images that are loaded in your application once so when you make the same request again, it doesn't necessarily need to load it from the server again.

To check this, you can run your application in Chrome, then run developer tools and go to the Network tab and in the filter section click on the Img label so it will filter by images only.

Once you do this try hitting refresh on your page and you will see that some images are loaded from either disk cache/memory cache thus eliminating the need to load from the server again and again.

[image: Network Tools]

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers by default cache but firebase storage's image is not cached

[Firebase storage Image cache not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337396/firebase-storage-image-cache-not-working)